# How to open "Paid" app page in iPhone's AppStore by clicking button in "Lite" app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I have 2 versions of an app. Lite and Paid.
I want to have a button in Lite version which when clicked opens App Store application on iPhone and shows the page for Paid version of the app.

How do I do this?
I DONT want to open Paid version iTunes page in Safari. It should open in App Store application only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work always (all OS):

```
http://itunes.apple.com/app/idYOUR_PAID_APP_ID
```

Code snippet (you can just copy & paste it):

```
#define YOUR_PAID_APP_ID 553834731 // replace with your paid app ID

static NSString *const iOSAppStoreURLFormat = @"http://itunes.apple.com/app/id%d"; // General link to the App Store

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: iOSAppStoreURLFormat,YOUR_PAID_APP_ID ]]]; // Would open the right link
```

Comment: Bad solution! iPhone opens Safari first, then AppStore.

Comment: @Altaveron I've updated the answer so you can remove those comment (seems irrelevant to me)